# How to check whether a proxy server is blocked in China

Tags: proxy

How do I check whether a proxy server is blocked in China?

[Website Pulse](http://www.websitepulse.com/help/testtools.china-test.html) has a tool for checking whether a website is blocked, but my proxy servers don't have web front end. Short of getting my own China-based proxy, what are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options are :

- make the data go through china (experimental solution)
- get your hand on the Chinese blacklist (which I doubt you can obtain) (theoretical solution)

To get the data to go through China you have the following options :

- use an available Chinese proxy (Google china and proxy)
- have a script on Chinese server or a server behind a Chinese proxy tell you if it works
- have someone in China make the test
- be in China

If you can't do any of those, you can't check it.

Comment: As I suspected. I was hoping there was a more comprehensive tool like the Website Pulse one, but I guess the silence speaks for itself.